# Borel functions and their equivalence to sets.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space. The following are equivalent:

1. $\ X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R} $ is a Borel function.
2. $\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)>a\}\in\mathcal{F}$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$.
3. $\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)< a\}\in\mathcal{F}$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$.
4. $\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega) \in B\}\in\mathcal{F}$ for all open subsets $B\subset\mathbb{R}$.
5. $\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega) \in B\}\in\mathcal{F}$ for all closed subsets $B\subset\mathbb{R}$.

How on earth would I prove this? I have no idea where to start. Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

1) $\Rightarrow$ 2) is clear since $(a;+\infty)$ is a Borel set.

2) $\Rightarrow$ 3) because $\{\omega, X(\Omega)<a\}=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}\{\omega\in\Omega, X(\omega)\leq a-1/n\}$ and each set of the union is of the form of the sets involved in 2), after taking complement.

3)$\Rightarrow$ 4) can be shown as the following: first show that it works when $B$ is an interval, then use the fact that an open subset of the real line can be written as a countable union of open intervals.

4)$\Rightarrow$ 5) using complement.

5)$\Rightarrow$ 1) Let $\mathcal A:=\{A\subset R, X^{-1}(A)\mbox{ is a Borel set}\}$. Show that $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.